# JQtouch event?

Tags: jquery, events, jqtouch

I'm trying to call a function on click of class `djl` but I don't know what's wrong. It's not working.

Here is my code:

```
$("a.dj").click(function(){
$.getJSON("http://sdsdds.com/sds.json",function(result){
$.each(result, function(i, field){
$("ul#alb").append("<li><a class='djl' href='#songs'>" + field.name + "</a></li>");
```

The above code works perfect but problem starts here:

```
$("a.djl").click(function(){
$('#songs').replaceWith('<div>fnuh</div>');
```

Help me out please.

Comment: the second code block isn't valid jquery code you now that don't you?

Comment: can you please post valid one may be im creating some mistakes

Comment: this code can't work if you don't close the scope of the function : });

Comment: well i know about closing them i just posted logic of event not full code

Comment: So what is not working ? Do you have any error in your console ?
The click doesn't trigger ?
Have you tried to put 'alert('test');' in your code for the click to see if it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect at the time of binding there is no element matchting the selector "a.djl". If so you need to use the live event for binding:

```
$("a.djl").live("click", function(){
  //your stuff to do
});
```